# In Android how to get the current height of BottomSheet while sliding it?

Tags: android

When I'm sliding the persistent bottom sheet inside my app, I want to know the current height of the bottom sheet at that moment. I tried with calling BottomSheetCallback's onSlide method but it didn't work.

```
    bottomSheetView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING == newState)
                Log.i("MainActivity", "onStateChanged  >>  " + bottomSheet.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onSlide  bottomSheet>>  " + bottomSheet.getHeight());
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onSlide  bottomSheetView>>  " + bottomSheetView.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm facing same issue have u got any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean "didn't work"? This is how I compute the current height while sliding:

```
    private val bottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            drawerHeight = bottomSheet.height * slideOffset // Current height of bottom sheet
        }

        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) = Unit
    }
```

Comment: For me its that after calling bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED, when onStateChanged is called with newState == STATE_EXPANDED, the bottomSheet.height is still 0.  If I expand again the height is correct

Answer (score 1):

I think the height won't change when sliding since the actual view of the bottom sheet is not changed. The bottom sheet itself just sliding down.

But you still can get the height by a little calculation using **locationOnScreen** of the bottomSheetView.

For example:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
    BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        var locationOnScreen: IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 0)
        bottomSheet.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
        Log.d(
            "BottomSheet",
            "slideOffset: $slideOffset - view height: ${locationOnScreen[0]},${locationOnScreen[1]}"
        )
    }

    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        Log.d("BottomSheet", "State: $newState")
    }
})
```

locationOnScreen's value keeps changing when the BottomSheet is sliding up/down.

Answer (score 0):

give id to your parent layout of bottom sheet then get your height , for example if your
parent is

```
 RelativeLayout relative  = findviewbyid (R.id.rel);
relative.getheight();
```

or depend your condition get height in another ways
you can always get your height or width of layouts in `onWindowFocusChanged` method

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

         int height = relative.getHeight();

     Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: yes maybe , cause i don't see your code , what is your mean doesn't work ? it give you null ?

Comment: onWindowFocusChanged will not be called continuously as the bottom sheet is sliding up/down. I want the height as the bottom sheet is being slide up/down.

Answer (score 0):

This is my option to get shift down.

```
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            int currentHeight = rootContainer.getHeight() - bottomSheet.getHeight();
            int bottomSheetShiftDown = currentHeight - bottomSheet.getTop();
            rootContainer.setPadding(
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    (mBottomSheet.getPeekHeight() + bottomSheetShiftDown));
                }
```

Comment: rootContainer.getHeight() & bottomSheet.getHeight() doesn't change it's value till I release the bottom sheet.

Comment: getPeekHeight() not change too

Comment: try to log bottomSheetShiftDown you will see value from 0 to -bottomSheet.getHeight() and this is your height when you shift it down - bottomSheet.getHeight() + bottomSheetShiftDown

Comment: when I try bottomSheet.getHeight() + bottomSheetShiftDown, till 1/3 way to slide up I get negative values.

Comment: because my case just for slide down.

Comment: while sliding down also it gives negative value, even when the view is not completely hidden.

Comment: ok, rootContainer = full screen height - bottom sheet height, this my first line of code, you do this?.  when you slide down bottomSheet.getTop() must grows. check it.

Comment: that doesn't seem efficient to change padding during a slide animation. i bet the gpu is not happy with that, but im glad it worked for you